# AndroidManifest tag for different versions and devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support

What `AndroidManifest.xml` tag would I use for Android versions 3.1 and 3.2 (phone and tablet) which would define screen density, as it would be filtered in the Google Play Store?

Comment: Sorry, which `AndroidManifest.xml` tags are you asking for?

Comment: i m talking about support screen tag so google play store understand currectly to filter device means show device or not into playstore app list i.e we use <supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"  like that into manifest.

Comment: So you're looking for an Android Manifest tag to define screen density?

Comment: yes sir, exactly  for 3.1 older and 3.2 higher device both

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any tags to declare screen density as Google would filter this automatically. It's filter would be based on what folders you are using to put images in for screen density.

For example, if I had the folders: `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable-mdpi`, upon uploading your app, this would be identified, and so Google would filter search results accordingly.

Just as a side note, the recommended (standard) folders you include to put images in with different screen densities are: `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` and `drawable-xxhdpi`.

On the Android website, you can read in more detail about [supporting different screen densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) as well as [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) when creating an Android app.

Comment: sir ,how can u say that dont need any tag have read anywhere else or any proof link i have read about this for handset and tablet tag into official site as following....

Comment: <manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />  <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />

Comment: Your question wasn't very clear. Send me the link to what you are referring to.

Comment: Declaring an App is Only for Tablets <manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: check this official link  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps

Comment: let me know what tag should i use??

Comment: If you want to distribute to specific screen densities, use the tag `android:screenDensity`. You can read about it on the link that you posted above.

Comment: so far i m talking about that bye the way those screen density mentioned into official blog i can use to filter app for particular density of  handset and tablet..

Comment: Yes. If you want your app to only be available to those users which have that specific density, use the `android:screenDensity` tag. Read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html).